# undefined method `exist?' - Feature... or bug?

Tags: ruby

I found some unexpected (to me) behavior in Ruby. Is this behavior a bug or a feature? I stumbled on this situation while writing my project.

To put it as succinctly as I can: if a class' name ends with ::File and that class inherits from another class, then the usual File class isn't used with "File", but instead the current class is used.

(Yes, that's as succinct as I could figure out how to make it.)

Consider the following code, which produces the [feature|bug]

```
class MyClass
end

class MyClass::File < MyClass
    def check
        File.exist?('./whatever.txt')
    end
end

myfile = MyClass::File.new
myfile.check
```

That code produces the following error:

```
./dev.rb:8:in `check': undefined method `exist?' for MyClass::File:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  exit
               exit!
    from ./dev.rb:13:in `<main>'
```

What's weird (to me, anyway) is that the error doesn't happen if MyClass::File doesn't inherit from MyClass. That is, if you remove the "< MyClass" part then there's no error.

Now, I can just hear some programmers muttering over their latte: *you shouldn't end a class name with ::File, that's just bad form*. Well, I really want my class called ::File because that's the type of object it represents. I just have this thing that I like to give classes meaningful names.

I found a work around by calling Object::File instead of just File:

```
Object::File.exist?('./whatever.txt')
```

I don't even know how I figured that out... I couldn't google anything about this [feature|bug] but I figured it out within 20 guesses. Got lucky, I guess.

So...

1) Is this a feature or a bug?
2) Did I use the right workaround?

Comment: That's just how constant names are resolved, `::File` would be the usual solution.

Comment: Note that it works as intended if you use `class MyClass; class Foo` (e.g. re-open the outer class). There's a [style guide note](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition) about this which says "Using the scope resolution operator can lead to surprising constant lookups due to Ruby's lexical scoping, which depends on the module nesting at the point of definition." It links to [this article](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html). I can't say I completely understand why this specific behavior happens though.